# Building graph with maps

Tags: c++

```
map <int, int[]> miasta;
miasta[0] = { {1,2,3} };
```

What do I need to do If i want to make a dictionary that contains that gets int and you can assign many integers to one int because I want to make a graph
in python I can just do that like this
cities = {1 : {1,2,3}, 2: {1, 2, 3}}
How do I do that in c++

Comment: You probably want to do `std::map<int, std::vector<int>>`. You can then do `miasta[0] = { 1, 2, 3 }`

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 map <int, vector<int>> miasta;
 miasta[0] = { {1,2,3} };
 cout << miasta[0];
} I did it like that and i get an error what can I do ?

Comment: Well, for one, re-read what I wrote and compare it to what you wrote, they're different. Secondly, you cannot print a vector like that.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use something like  `map<int, vector<int>>` or `map<int, list<int>>` or `map<int, deque<int>>` (see [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), and [deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque))

Addressing your comment you cannot directly cout a vector. You have to use a range based for-loop:

```
for(const auto& i: miasta[0])
    std::cout << i << " ";
```